# Collective term for bees, wasps, hornets, etc

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Is there a collective term to describe bees, wasps, hornets, and the like?

I'm looking for a term that refers to insects that look like bees, wasps and hornets that could also sting. I'm trying to translate a Japanese word (that can mean all these without being specific) into English. Below are two of the many sites that I checked, which did not give me what I was looking for.

https://honeybeesuite.com/bees-and-their-families/

https://www.animalwised.com/differences-between-wasps-hornets-and-bees-670.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82067/discussion-on-question-by-chcr-collective-term-for-bees-wasps-hornets-etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple umbrella term in which bees, hornets, wasps, yellow jackets, etc. belong to is

**Stinging insects**. The more scientific term is **[Hymenoptera](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2NJ8VF8jIKYC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=%22stinging%20insects%22%20Latin&source=bl&ots=0T4bSW72Zm&sig=qXLGIcgaYyvSn6uA57XF6MySWHs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCkdvRsYDdAhUCF5AKHc6PCNA4FBDoATANegQIChAB#v=onepage&q=%22stinging%20insects%22%20Latin&f=false)**

> **Stinging insects** have long been known to cause allergic reactions in humans. The earliest recorded death from an allergic reaction caused by a stinging insect was that of Pharaoh Menes of Egypt who died in 2641 B.C. after being stung by either a hornet or a wasp.
>
> - Bees, wasps, and ants are stinging insects belonging to the order Hymenoptera, which is Latin for "membrane-winged." **The 3 families of greatest medical significance within this order are *Apidae*** (honeybees and bumblebees), ***Vespidae*** (yellow jackets, hornets, and wasps), **and *Formicidae*** (fire ants).
> - Hymenoptera stings cause a wide spectrum of illness ranging from benign nuisance to life-threatening toxicity and anaphylaxis.
>
> <sub>*[Hymenoptera Envenomation](https://www.ebmedicine.net/topics.php?paction=showTopic&topic_id=145)*</sub>

[image]

The scientific journal, *[Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/ouch-an-interview-with-entomology-s-king-of-sting/)*, uses the expression “stinging insects” several instances in their article entitled *Ouch! An Interview with Entomology's King of Sting*

Comment: Precis and helpful answer.